# OpenGL (Python) - applying an STMap (UVmap) to an image?

Tags: python, opengl

i have the following code that loads and displays (using PyQt) an image on the screen:

```
gVShader = """
              attribute vec4 position;
              attribute vec2 texture_coordinates;
              varying vec2 v_texture_coordinates;
              void main() {
                  v_texture_coordinates = texture_coordinates;
                  v_texture_coordinates.y = 1.0 - v_texture_coordinates.y;
                  gl_Position = position;
              }"""

gFShader = """
              uniform sampler2D texture1;
              uniform sampler2D texture2;
              varying vec2 v_texture_coordinates;

              void main() {
                  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, texture2.rg);
              }"""


class ProjectiveGLViewer(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProjectiveGLViewer, self).__init__(parent)

    def initializeGL(self):

        vshader = QtOpenGL.QGLShader(QtOpenGL.QGLShader.Vertex, self)
        if not vshader.compileSourceCode(gVShader):
            print vshader.log()

        fshader = QtOpenGL.QGLShader(QtOpenGL.QGLShader.Fragment, self)
        if not fshader.compileSourceCode(gFShader):
            print fshader.log()

        self._program = QtOpenGL.QGLShaderProgram()
        self._program.addShader(vshader)
        self._program.addShader(fshader)
        self._program.link()
        self._program.bind()

        # data array (2 [position], 4 [color])

        data = np.array([-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)

        self.bufferID = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.bufferID)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.nbytes, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        loc = self._program.attributeLocation("position")
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 16, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        loc = self._program.attributeLocation("texture_coordinates")
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 16, ctypes.c_void_p(8))

        image = QtGui.QImage("image.jpg")
        ptr = image.bits()
        ptr.setsize(image.byteCount())
        image_data = np.asarray(ptr).reshape(image.width(), image.height(), 4)

        self._imageTextureID = glGenTextures(1)

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  self._imageTextureID)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width(), image.height(), 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data)

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        self._program.setUniformValue('texture1', 0)


    image2 = QtGui.QImage("st_map.tif")
    ptr2 = image2.bits()
    ptr2.setsize(image2.byteCount())
    image_data2 = np.asarray(ptr).reshape(image2.width(), image2.height(), 4)

    self._stTextureID = glGenTextures(1)

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  self._stTextureID)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image2.width(), image2.height(), 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data2)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)

    self._program.setUniformValue('texture2', 1)

    def paintGL(self):
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.bufferID)
        glClearColor(0, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
```

Now, i want to use an STMap (UVmap) to remap the pixels of that image. 
For those of you who aren't familiar with it, an STMap looks like this: [link](http://www.imagineersystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/UndistortSTMap.jpg)
But could have many shapes.
It's the same size as my original image, and contains only Red and Green channels (Blue is empty). The Red represents the X axis and the Green represents the Y. 
So for example, to get the new coordinates of the pixel that's at position [100,100] in my original image, i would go to that same position in the STMap and look for that pixel's Red channel value (that would be the new X value) and Green value (new Y value).

So how can i do that? I'm not too sure..
I tried adding the STMap texture but it wouldn't let me use it's Red and Green channel values (see fragment shader).Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've edited my code with something that i tried and didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have all resources I cannot run you code here.

From the shader point of view, you can modify `texture1` coordinates by using `texture2` coordinates.
There are many ways to do that, for example you could just translate them by adding UVMap values to it. Here, `texture2` contains UVMap data:

```
 uniform sampler2D texture1;
 uniform sampler2D texture2;
 varying vec2 v_texture_coordinates;

 vec2 my_new_coords;
 vec4 uvmap;
 void main() {
     // uv map data at current position
     uvmap = texture2D(texture2, v_texture_coordinates);

     // map current position by using uv map data
     my_new_coords.x = v_texture_coordinates.x + uvmap.r;
     my_new_coords.y = v_texture_coordinates.y + uvmap.g;

     // sample texture 2 with new mapped coordinates
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, my_new_coords);
 }
```

Or if you just want to use the coordinates from UVMap you can do

```
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, uvmap);
```